# Incorrect Return Value for Comparison Function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, comparison, operators

The function, expensiveItem(menu), should return the most expensive item in the array, meals. In this case, it should return "Double Quarter Pounder with Cheese". Instead, it returns "Double Cheeseburger". Where did I go wrong in my code?

```js
var item1 = {
  name: "Big Mac",
  price: 3.99,
  calories: 530
};
var item2 = {
  name: "Filet-O-Fish",
  price: 3.79,
  calories: 390
};
var item3 = {
  name: "Double Cheeseburger",
  price: 1.59,
  calories: 430
};
var item4 = {
  name: "Double Quarter Pounder with Cheese",
  price: 4.79,
  calories: 740
};
var item5 = {
  name: "Chicken McNuggets",
  price: 4.49,
  calories: 190
};

var meals = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];


function init() {
  var lowestCost = document.getElementById('cheapestItem');

  lowestCost.onclick = function() {
    cheapestItem(meals);
  }

  var highestCost = document.getElementById('highestCost');

  highestCost.onclick = function() {
    expensiveItem(meals);
  }

}

window.onload = init;


// return name of cheapest item on menu
function cheapestItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg1'); // is this necessary? Code works fine without it...

  var cheapestItem = operation(menu, "less");
  msg1.innerHTML = "The cheapest item is " + cheapestItem;
}

// return name of most expensive item on menu
function expensiveItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg2');

  var expensiveItem = operation(menu, "greater");
  msg2.innerHTML = "The most expensive item is " + expensiveItem;
}

//return result based on given comparator operator
function operation(menu, op) {
  var v1 = menu[0].price;
  var item;

  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    var v2 = menu[i].price;


    if ((op == "less" && (v2 < v1)) ||
      (op == "greater" && (v2 > v1))) {
      result = v2;
      item = menu[i].name;
    }
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <input type="button" id="cheapestItem" value="Cheapest Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg1">message 1</p>

  <input type="button" id="highestCost" value="Most Expensive Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg2">message 2</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a side node, you need to assign value to item `var item = menu[0].name;`, because it will fail if the first element is the largest or smallest, depending on `op`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
if ((op == "less" && (v2 < v1)) || (op == "greater" && (v2 > v1)))
```

You are only comparing `v1` and `v2` but you should also assign `v1` value of `v2` if condition is satisfied.

#### Explanation:

Following are the values in loop

```js
3.99 3.99
3.99 3.79
3.99 1.59
3.99 4.79
4.79 4.49
```

If you notice, last 2 operations satisfies the condition. So you will get the latter one.

```js
var item1 = {
  name: "Big Mac",
  price: 3.99,
  calories: 530
};
var item2 = {
  name: "Filet-O-Fish",
  price: 3.79,
  calories: 390
};
var item3 = {
  name: "Double Cheeseburger",
  price: 1.59,
  calories: 430
};
var item4 = {
  name: "Double Quarter Pounder with Cheese",
  price: 4.79,
  calories: 740
};
var item5 = {
  name: "Chicken McNuggets",
  price: 4.49,
  calories: 190
};

var meals = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];


function init() {
  var lowestCost = document.getElementById('cheapestItem');

  lowestCost.onclick = function() {
    cheapestItem(meals);
  }

  var highestCost = document.getElementById('highestCost');

  highestCost.onclick = function() {
    expensiveItem(meals);
  }

}

window.onload = init;


// return name of cheapest item on menu
function cheapestItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg1'); // is this necessary? Code works fine without it...

  var cheapestItem = operation(menu, "less");
  msg1.innerHTML = "The cheapest item is " + cheapestItem;
}

// return name of most expensive item on menu
function expensiveItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg2');

  var expensiveItem = operation(menu, "greater");
  msg2.innerHTML = "The most expensive item is " + expensiveItem;
}

//return result based on given comparator operator
function operation(menu, op) {
  var v1 = menu[0].price;
  var item;

  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    var v2 = menu[i].price;

    if ((op == "less" && (v2 <= v1)) ||
      (op == "greater" && (v2 >= v1))) {
      result = v1 = v2;
      item = menu[i].name;
    }
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <input type="button" id="cheapestItem" value="Cheapest Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg1">message 1</p>

  <input type="button" id="highestCost" value="Most Expensive Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg2">message 2</p>
</body>
```

#### Alternate Way

Sort your array in `init`. Now you dont have to loop to get min and max values.

**Note:** Its bad practice to use `window.load = function`, you should use `window.addEventListener('load', function)` instead

```js
var item1 = {
  name: "Big Mac",
  price: 3.99,
  calories: 530
};
var item2 = {
  name: "Filet-O-Fish",
  price: 3.79,
  calories: 390
};
var item3 = {
  name: "Double Cheeseburger",
  price: 1.59,
  calories: 430
};
var item4 = {
  name: "Double Quarter Pounder with Cheese",
  price: 4.79,
  calories: 740
};
var item5 = {
  name: "Chicken McNuggets",
  price: 4.49,
  calories: 190
};

var meals = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];
var OP_LESS = "less";
var OP_GREATER = "greater";

function init() {
  var lowestCost = document.getElementById('cheapestItem');

  lowestCost.onclick = function() {
    cheapestItem(meals);
  }

  var highestCost = document.getElementById('highestCost');

  highestCost.onclick = function() {
    expensiveItem(meals);
  }
  sortData();
}

function sortData(){
  meals.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.price > b.price ? 1 : a.price < b.price ? -1 : 0
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);

// return name of cheapest item on menu
function cheapestItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg1'); // is this necessary? Code works fine without it...

  var cheapestItem = operation(menu, OP_LESS);
  msg1.innerHTML = "The cheapest item is " + cheapestItem;
}

// return name of most expensive item on menu
function expensiveItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg2');
  var expensiveItem = operation(menu, OP_GREATER);
  msg2.innerHTML = "The most expensive item is " + expensiveItem;
}

//return result based on given comparator operator
function operation(menu, op) {
  return (op === OP_LESS ? meals[0] : meals[meals.length-1]).name
}
```

```html
<body>

  <input type="button" id="cheapestItem" value="Cheapest Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg1">message 1</p>

  <input type="button" id="highestCost" value="Most Expensive Item">
  </div>
  <p id="msg2">message 2</p>
</body>
```

Comment: ohhh I changed the variable names but never changed 'result' to 'v1'. Thanks, good catch! :)

Answer (score 0):

You always compare with initial v1 value, when you find the "greater" you should set the new value to var v1.

```
if ((op == "less" && (v2 < v1)) ||
    (op == "greater" && (v2 > v1))) {
    result = v2;
    v1=v2; //Set new greater/lower value
    item = menu[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Yup I see now, I changed the variable names but never changed 'result' to 'v1'. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use only one variable to test against and to return

```
function operation(menu, op) {
    var price = menu[0].price,
        item = menu[0].name;

    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        if (
            op === "less"    && menu[i].price < price ||
            op === "greater" && menu[i].price > price
        ) {
            price = menu[i].price;
            item = menu[i].name;
        }
    }
    console.log(item);
    return item;
}
```

```js
var item1 = {      name: "Big Mac",      price: 3.99,      calories: 530    };
var item2 = {      name: "Filet-O-Fish",      price: 3.79,      calories: 390    };
var item3 = {      name: "Double Cheeseburger",      price: 1.59,      calories: 430    };
var item4 = {      name: "Double Quarter Pounder with Cheese",      price: 4.79,      calories: 740
};
var item5 = {      name: "Chicken McNuggets",      price: 4.49,      calories: 190    };

var meals = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];

function init() {
  var lowestCost = document.getElementById('cheapestItem');
  lowestCost.onclick = function() {
    cheapestItem(meals);
  }

  var highestCost = document.getElementById('highestCost');

  highestCost.onclick = function() {
    expensiveItem(meals);
  }
}

window.onload = init;

// return name of cheapest item on menu
function cheapestItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg1'); // is this necessary? Code works fine without it...

  var cheapestItem = operation(menu, "less");
  msg1.innerHTML = "The cheapest item is " + cheapestItem;
}

// return name of most expensive item on menu
function expensiveItem(menu) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg2');

  var expensiveItem = operation(menu, "greater");
  msg2.innerHTML = "The most expensive item is " + expensiveItem;
}

//return result based on given comparator operator
function operation(menu, op) {
  var price = menu[0].price,
      item = menu[0].name;

  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    if (op == "less" && menu[i].price < price || op == "greater" && menu[i].price > price) {
      price = menu[i].price;
      item = menu[i].name;
    }
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
}
```

```html
  <input type="button" id="cheapestItem" value="Cheapest Item">
  <p id="msg1">message 1</p>
  <input type="button" id="highestCost" value="Most Expensive Item">
  <p id="msg2">message 2</p>
```

Comment: Hi Nina, is there a reason why you suggest this? I thought assigning 'menu[i].price' to a variable would keep the code cleaner and make it less redundant. But maybe it doesn't make much of a difference?

Comment: a step further, i would take only the index of the menu, which is the min or max. only for returning a value, i would return the name of `menu[index]`. the reason to use only one vsariable is to keep it always to a decent value. if you use two variables, you may mixed up the context of the variables.